# Is there a reason a UIViewControllerRepresentable should never be a class?

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

Let's say that you don't really need SwiftUI features. I.e. you don't have `import SwiftUI` in your file. Instead, you only require

```swift
import protocol SwiftUI.UIViewControllerRepresentable
```

In general, you're going to have to involve a delegate object: [an `AnyObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontrollerdelegate) at best, and usually, because the UIKit APIs are old, an `NSObject`.

The common pattern is to use a [Coordinator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/makecoordinator()-32trb) class for that, and have the View itself be a struct, but is there always point in that indirection?

Here's an example which hasn't given me any trouble in practice:

```swift
import Combine
import MultipeerConnectivity
import protocol SwiftUI.UIViewControllerRepresentable

extension MCBrowserViewController {
  final class View: NSObject {
    init(
      serviceType: String,
      session: MCSession,
      peerCountRange: ClosedRange<Int>? = nil
    ) {
      self.serviceType = serviceType
      self.session = session
      self.peerCountRange = peerCountRange
    }

    private let serviceType: String
    private unowned let session: MCSession
    private let peerCountRange: ClosedRange<Int>?

    private let didFinishSubject = CompletionSubject()
    private let wasCancelledSubject = CompletionSubject()
  }
}

// MARK: - internal
extension MCBrowserViewController.View {
  var didFinishPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> { didFinishSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher() }
  var wasCancelledPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> { wasCancelledSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher() }
}

// MARK: - private
private extension MCBrowserViewController {
  typealias CompletionSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>
}

// MARK: - UIViewControllerRepresentable
extension MCBrowserViewController.View: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MCBrowserViewController {
    let browser = MCBrowserViewController(
      serviceType: serviceType,
      session: session
    )

    browser.delegate = self

    if let peerCountRange = peerCountRange {
      browser.minimumNumberOfPeers = peerCountRange.lowerBound
      browser.maximumNumberOfPeers = peerCountRange.upperBound
    }

    return browser
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_: MCBrowserViewController, context _: Context) { }
}

// MARK: - MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate
extension MCBrowserViewController.View: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {
  func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_: MCBrowserViewController) {
    didFinishSubject.send()
  }

  func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_: MCBrowserViewController) {
    wasCancelledSubject.send()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full detailed answer for your question, but your solution have some problems.

In SwiftUI, if we update a `View`, it calls `init` to recreate the `View`, and then call `updateUIViewController`.

In your case, whenever you update your `View`, not only your view is recreated, your two subjects will be recreated too, so anything attaches to the `Publisher` after the recreation won't receive events any more.

maybe that's the reason we prefer to use `Coordinator`.

Comment: It sounds like you’re saying that makeCoordinator + makeUIViewController run one time, the same as State and Binding storage allocation, no matter how many times the view is created. Accurate?

Comment: @Jessy yes, it's accurate.

Comment: So then, wouldn’t returning `self` from `makeCoordinator` solve the problem you’ve mentioned? I’ve never seen anyone do that either.

Comment: @Jessy you can test it yourself easily.

Comment: The question wasn't for me. It was for you to think about. (And if you can wrap your head around it, please add it to the answer.) Consider how returning self as the coordinator would differ from what I'm proposing.

Comment: @Jessy it depends on how you use your `publisher`, if you use it like this `View { }.xxxPublisher.sink {}`, it won't work.